# How to get first and last dayName of month in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a problem. I want to have First and last dayName of some Month. e.g if i pass Month name as January and year 2012, it should give me First day of January 2012 and Last day in January 2012. thnx

Comment: [Welcome to SO, don't forget to **take the SO Tour** it will guide you on how to best use this site](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel we're not supposed to do that anymore http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122987

Comment: Thanks, @Jodrell - I didn't know about that. To clarify, Fahad, what I meant to say is that it would be very beneficial to both yourself and the community if you provide a little more detail in your questions and include what you have done so far, so that we know that you have attempted to solve the issue yourself before asking us. The community prefers to allocate more time to those who show that they are putting in the effort, than to those who do not.

Comment: @Zachary Kniebel: thnx for clarifying, I was new to do so, Infact i was writing my own code to do so, then i thought why shouldn't i use the datetime to do so...? but i didn't have any idea of where to start that's why i posted here and got my answer..well thnx for considering me as novice. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every month starts the number 1 but since last day number can be different, you can use [`DateTime.DaysInMonth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx) method for this.

> Returns the number of days in the specified month and year.

For last day name;

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2012, 1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(2012, 1));
Console.WriteLine(dt.DayOfWeek);

//Tuesday
```

For first day name;

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
Console.WriteLine(dt.DayOfWeek);

//Sunday
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/CbOeuE).

Comment: The user asked for January 2012. Please modify your code so that the OP doesn't need to write his own.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Why not? Updated.

Comment: but what day was the big bang?

Comment: I guess we can infer Jesus was born on a Sunday since `DateTime.MinValue.DayOfWeek == "Monday"`.

Comment: Thnx Soner Gonul it solved my problem.
Cyborgx37: thnx to you too.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the enum value for the day of the week of the first and last day of a month like so:

```
int month = 1;
DateTime date = new DateTime(2012, month, 1);

DayOfWeek firstDay = date.DayOfWeek;
DayOfWeek lastDay = date.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).DayOfWeek;
```

If you need to convert the day of the week names to localized strings:

```
string firstDayString = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetDayName(firstDay);
string lastDayString = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetDayName(lastDay);
```

If you need to convert from a localized month name string to a month number:

```
string monthName = "January";
int monthNumber = DateTime.ParseExact(monthName, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ).Month;
```

Putting it all together:

```
string monthName = "January";
int year = 2012;

int monthNumber = DateTime.ParseExact(monthName, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month;

DateTime date = new DateTime(year, monthNumber, 1);

DayOfWeek firstDay = date.DayOfWeek;
DayOfWeek lastDay = date.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).DayOfWeek;

string firstDayString = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetDayName(firstDay);
string lastDayString = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetDayName(lastDay);

Console.WriteLine("First day of month = " + firstDayString);
Console.WriteLine("Last day of month = " + lastDayString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string month = "January";
int year = 2012;
DateTime firstDay = DateTime.Parse(month + ", 1 " + year, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime lastDay = firstDay.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new DateTime(2013, 1, 15);

var nextMonth = date.AddMonths(1);

var firstDay = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1).DayOfWeek;

var lastDay = new DateTime(nextMonth.Year, nextMonth.Month, 1).AddDays(-1).DayOfWeek;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This code.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime firstDayOfTheMonth = new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 1);
string firstDay = firstDayOfTheMonth.DayOfWeek.ToString();
DateTime lastday = firstDayOfTheMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
string lastdayofMonth = lastday.DayOfWeek.ToString();
```